# Is there an equivalent of Kotlin Flow in Swift

Tags: swift, kotlin

In Kotlin, when I save the data to room db and I use flow to retrieve it and display to the UI, any changes I made to the db reflects the UI using collect.

For example this is in my Dao class

```
    @Query("select * from ....")
    abstract fun getAllAsFlow(headerId : Long) : Flow<List<ProductAudit>>
```

Now in the UI I use collect to display the retrieved data.

```
var audits by mutableStateOf<List<ProductAudit>>(listOf())
.... 

fun load() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
      database.getAllAsFlow(1).collect {
      audits = it
    }
  }
}
```

When the datbase is changed, I instantly see those changes in the UI.

Is there something like that in coredata and swift?

Comment: There is NSFetchedResultsController, and FetchRequest for SwiftUI.

Comment: I was using FetchRequest to retrieve my data. But that doesn't trigger anything when I change the data. Like insert, update or delete. I added some sample code just to be clear.

Comment: It depends on your Database provider `@FetchRequest` the wrapper being the important part can provide updates when using CoreData+SwiftUI but different databases have different solutions. An `AsyncStream` is likely closer to a `Flow` but something needs to trigger it, there is no one solution it is very case specific.